# In Reportlab what does splitbyRows does?

Tags: python, reportlab

Trying to add one big table into PDF using reportlab. But the content is crossing across the left and right margin of page.

Even if i set the columnWidth to get the fixed width of table, the content looks too fuzzy. All the cell contents are in flowable format.

Can I solve using splitbyRows?? Or what is the best approach?

```
    from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle, Image, Paragraph, Spacer,  LongTable
    from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4, inch, cm
    import numpy as np
    from reportlab.lib import colors

    # Pdf design parameters
    FONT_STYLE_BOLD = 'Helvetica-Bold'
    FONT_STYLE = 'Helvetica'

    def addtable(col, row, table_data):
        """
        Add table to the pdf
        """
        # Defininig table structure(nos of rows, nos of columns, size of rows, size of columns)
        #tableobj = Table(table_data, col * [3.26 * inch], row * [0.25 * inch], hAlign='LEFT')
        tableobj = Table(table_data, colWidths = [1 * inch] * col, splitByRow=2, rowSplitRange=(5,20))

        # Defining Table style

        tablestyle = [('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (0, -1), FONT_STYLE),
                      ('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, 0), FONT_STYLE_BOLD),
                      ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.lightgrey),
                      ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.grey),
                      ('RIGHTPADDING', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 3),
                      ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.grey),
                      ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 9),
                      ('ALIGN', (1, 0), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),
                      ]


        tableobj.setStyle(TableStyle(tablestyle))
        elements.append(tableobj)


    elements = []

    clust_data = [["Name", "Date", "Address", "CONTACT DETAILS", "JOB", "DESCRIPTION", "MISC", "JOB", "DESCRIPTION", "MISC", "OTHER", 'FIELD11', 'FIELD22'],
    ["Name", "Date", "Address", "CONTACT DETAILS", "JOB", "DESCRIPTION", "MISC", "JOB", "DESCRIPTION", "MISC", "OTHER", 'FIELD11', 'FIELD22'],
    ["Name", "Date", "Address", "CONTACT DETAILS", "JOB", "DESCRIPTION", "MISC", "JOB", "DESCRIPTION", "MISC", "OTHER", 'FIELD11', 'FIELD22'],
    ["Name", "Date", "Address", "CONTACT DETAILS", "JOB", "DESCRIPTION", "MISC", "JOB", "DESCRIPTION", "MISC", "OTHER", 'FIELD11', 'FIELD22'],
        ]

    addtable(len(clust_data[0]), len(clust_data), clust_data)

    doc = SimpleDocTemplate('table.pdf', pagesize=A4)
    doc.topMargin = .13 * inch
    doc.build(elements)

    del elements[:]
```

Comment: maybe it will help, here is a pdf docs https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This is old, so i'm sure you don't care anymore. But here's the answer.

Your A4 pagesize is `(8.27x11.69)in`. In `addtable` you say create me a table with 13 columns (`len(data[0])`). And make them all 1 inch wide (`colWidths = [1 * inch] * col`).

Since 13in + margin > 8.27in, reportlab draws items off the page.

Hard to find documentation tip. `colWidths=['*']` will set all columns equal width, filling only the usable page width.